# Как перебрать значения атрибутов на странице?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('a.popup-ajax').popover({
    "html": true,
    "content": function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/heroespage',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                var title = $("a.popup-ajax").attr("data-heroid");
                console.log(response[title]['id']);
                var name = response[title]['name'];
                var role = response[title]['role'];
                var img = response[title]['img'];
                var typeAttack = response[title]['typeAttack'];
                $("a.popup-ajax").attr('data-content', '<div  class="hero-footnote"><img src="'+ img +'" alt=> <div class="hero-footnote__desc"><h3>'+ name +'</h3><p>'+ typeAttack+'</p><span>'+ role +'</span></div> </div>');


            }
        })
    }
});
```

Здесь я беру значение атрибута:

```
var title = $("a.popup-ajax").attr("data-heroid");
```

там хранится `id`, соответственно потом этот `id` подставляется в `response[title]` и выводится нужная мне инфа. Все хорошо, когда атрибут `data-heroid` один на странице, но если их несколько, то берется значение только первого.
Как переделать код, чтобы он брал значения каждого элемента на который я навожу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/

> **content**   ... If a function is given, it will be called with its `this`
> reference set to the element that the `popover` is attached to.
>
> **content**   ... функция вызывается в контексте (`this`) элемента, к которому прикреплен `popover`.

```
$('a.popup-ajax').popover({
    "html": true,
    "content": function(){
        var element = this; // !!!
        $.ajax({
            url: '/heroespage',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                var title = $(element).attr("data-heroid");  // !!!
                console.log(response[title]['id']);
                var name = response[title]['name'];
                var role = response[title]['role'];
                var img = response[title]['img'];
                var typeAttack = response[title]['typeAttack'];
                 /* !!! */$(element).attr('data-content', '<div  class="hero-footnote"><img src="'+ img +'" alt=> <div class="hero-footnote__desc"><h3>'+ name +'</h3><p>'+ typeAttack+'</p><span>'+ role +'</span></div> </div>');
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Как же я вам благодарен) Спасибо)еще небольшой вопросец. Не знаете почему окно popover появляется только со второго раза при наведении на элемент?

Comment: @ДенисДоня Хм, давайте думать. Где вызывается код `$('a.popup-ajax').popover({ ... });`?

Comment: в моем js файле.

Comment: @ДенисДоня Это понятно :). Подозреваю, что он находится в обработчике события `mouseover` или подобного. А надо вызывать его на загрузку страницы в `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Comment: Да уже могу немного тупить, больше 15 часов сижу над сайтом) Он не находится не в каком обработчике) выложил код как есть $(document).ready(function(){...}); - не помогло

Comment: Спасибо еще раз за помощь, уже днем буду думать как это решить)